# Related List Records access for PortalUser

Tags: security, sharing

How do I create the Account sharing rules to customer portal user based on this current setup:

1. Account is "Private"
2. Contact is "Control by Parent".

I have created a customerPortal user called 'Manager' in sandbox. Manager will login the portal and he can see the all contacts details. Currenlty he can see the only contact which is related to Manager(Portal User) Account. **how he can see the All contacts related to some other Accounts**. Please help...

Comment: Venkat, Can you simplify above paragraph? Its bit difficult to understand it.

Comment: How to create the Account sharing rule to customer portal user. I give Default Access for 
1.Account is "Private" 
2. Contact is "Control by Parent".

i create the customerPortal user called Manager in sandbox.Manger will login the portal and he can see the all contacts details.
currenlty he can see the only contact which is related to Manager(Portal User) Account. 

how he can see the All contacts related to some other Accounts.

Please help....

Comment: Please try to avoid using the salesforce-crm tag, almost everything is salesforce related. Choosing more specific tags will help attract people with the right knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Goto 'Security Control'->'Sharing Settings'
Create Sharing rule for Accounts.

Select 'Rule Type' as 'Based on Criteria'

Criteria 'Account Name' 'Not equals to' 'sgregrtgrtgrth'- this will always evaluate to true.

Share with - 'Public Groups' 'All Customer Portal Users'

Done.

Comment: Hi @Ganesh Thanks for Your reply we are not implement VF pages we are using standard customer portal url

Comment: << Manager(Portal User) related to Test(Account)
in sharing setting we delcared Based on criteria is Account Name equal to "Test" and Default Account, Contract and Asset Access  is Read-Write but still no luck...

Comment: Change criteria to as mentioned to answer, this criteria must always evaluate to True.

Comment: i change the criteria as per your answer but it doesn't show the records in portal page..it shows only contact owned records.

Comment: What is profile of your user?

Comment: Overage High VolumeCustomer Portal